# Why are the imported libraries in python so much faster than code manually written?

Tags: python, libraries

I have been playing around with square root algorithms, and I have noticed that no matter how efficient my function is, it is still orders of magnitude slower than the math.sqrt() function imported in pycharm. I assumed that I was simply inefficient with my code until I tested the math.sqrt() function against a function that simply did 1*1 one and the math.sqrt() function was still faster. I could not conceive of any algorithm to find the square root of a number that was faster than a single operation. This is my algorithm.

```
number = 1.2 * pow(2, math.floor(math.log(num, 2) / 2))
for i in range(5):
  number = (number + num / number) / 2
  return number
```

Comment: The x86/x64 processor has a square root instruction built-in.  That instruction does a Taylor series and runs in 18 cycles.  On a 3 GHz chip, that's 6 nanoseconds.  Nothing you can do will beat that.

Comment: `math.sqrt` is a wrapper for the `sqrt` function in the C language `math.h`, and its execution speed is much faster than the python level algebra operation.

Comment: Going wider: Most things in CPython and the stdlib are implemented in C, so trying to do something the implementation does, but at the Python level will likely be slower.

Comment: @wkl that's true for most things, but not universally.  Algorithms still count for something. I have Python code that can convert an integer to a string faster than `str` if the number is over about 100000 digits.

Answer (score -1):

I am just going to summarise the comments

Python is an interpreted language, it runs line by line

Some of the built-in functions are linked to C functions, not Python functions which are much faster at completing mathematical equations

I would recommend using the built-in functions for performance but I used to write the functions myself while learning Python

Cheers,
Daniel